# CSS Grid Layout for flowing text by line by column

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am displaying verse: poetry and song lyrics.
I have one layout in which the lyrics flow as multi-column text.  I have it working with flex layout, but it is not 100% to my satisfaction.  See this codepen: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/WNNEBgV

The remaining issue is the horizontal spacing of the columns. Flex layout spreads the columns as if I had set an alt version of `align-items:space-between`.  I want the columns to align left, which can be accomplished only by setting the width of the container `<div>` to one pixel greater than the width at which it starts scrolling horizontally, the minimum width for displaying all the text.

It seems to me that there should be a way to do this with grid layout, but I have not been able to make it happen.  I have tried a variety of settings, including the various auto flow settings.

Is there a solution for this in CSS, or do I have to rely on JavaScript?  I have a way of doing it in JS, and I already have code that manipulates these elements, but I'd much rather do it in CSS. It seems like a supremely reasonable layout request, at least to me.  The biggest problems I've encountered with grid layout are the need to set the number of rows and columns and to size those columns.  I want that to be all automatic because otherwise I'm still writing JS code to set those values.

Comment: you better use column CSS or a grid for that : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOOxNRY exemple with column CSS , which is a typical use to span text through columns. (br cannot be wrap in a span), hr, would be the one thing to do. Also, you should use a p to wrap each peaces of text  and make groups of 8 spans and probably avoid br or hr not needed anymore ...

Comment: While waiting for a feedback, about the html , it should be readable without any style , if it is, the structure is probabbly the good one, if it is not, the structure has to be rethink.

Comment: @G-Cyr - Thank for the reference to the `<hr>` tag.  But your codepen does not align the columns correctly.  Flexbox with `align-content:flex-start` solves the issue, per the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:300px;  
  overflow-x:scroll;
  /* align block to start*/
  align-content: flex-start; 
}
span {
  padding:0 8px;
  /* align child block to start*/
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `align-content` property.  It works without setting the spans to the `align-self` setting.  I have updated the codepen.  Thanks!

Comment: if you want to learn about flex-box characteristics review https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  its very interactive